# Regular expression javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello everyone I would like to create regex that will allow letter PK or numbers from 0 to 12 or 00,01,02,... to 12, null value or empty string? I tried this but if I entered 13 my regex indicated true instead of false. Here is my regex:

```
var myReg = /^0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|[PK]{2}|null|$/;
```

I tested PK letters and that worked fine, also I should not let them use lower case for those two letters.

Also I'm wondering if this would be a good regex for state abbreviation check?

```
var ckState = /^\b([A-Z]{2})\b$/;
```

Comment: you need to wrap them in a group, then you can just make the group optional instead of a blank use case

Comment: You'll have to group your alternation, placing the anchors outside this group. Otherwise they are part of one of the alternatives.

Comment: Your case includes the end of line, `... | $`

Comment: Can you provide any example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/B4MCg7/2)

```
^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|PK|null)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/e4IVp23dp54uU3HX)

### Description

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
    1st Capturing Group (0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|PK|null)?
        ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
        1st Alternative 0?[0-9]
            0? matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
                ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
            Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]
                0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)
        2nd Alternative 1[0-2]
            1 matches the character 1 literally (case sensitive)
            Match a single character present in the list below [0-2]
                0-2 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 2 (ASCII 50) (case sensitive)
        3rd Alternative PK
            PK matches the characters PK literally (case sensitive)
        4th Alternative null
            null matches the characters null literally (case sensitive)
```

### Notes

I removed `{2}` from `[PK]{2}` because this is stating any two of the characters `P` or `K`.  Allowing `PP`, `PK`, `KK`, `KP`

Comment: Just an extra link regex101.com is useful for visualization as well.

Comment: If I removed {2} my regex indicating false if I have PK value.

Comment: \b(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|PK|null)\b

And just a small optimization to the regex :)  searches for any of the required standing on their own or within a string.

Comment: What is b stands for? Also if I want for example just to allow length of 50, null or empty string how that should look like? I used this /^.{1,50}|null|$/. Not 100% sure if this is right.

Comment: @tolmera agreed, I assumed that it was the whole string, the above example uses those flags purely as an example to search all of the listed test strings

Comment: @espresso_coffee do you mean the above string can repeat up to a length of 50 characters max?

Comment: No, this just should allowed length of 50 or null or empty string. Completely separate regex.

Comment: @espresso_coffee so PK or 0-12 or 00-12 can happen literally 50 characters long? Or the total string must start with this then can be 50 characters?  Can you provide some example strings?

Comment: @abc123 That one is fine but I'm just wondering in my second regex that i'm working on I should allowed only strings of length from 0 to 50 or null or empty string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125516/discussion-between-abc123-and-espresso-coffee).